# Two queries – one with checkbox ticked, one without – comparing meta_query

Tags: custom-post-types, wp-query, meta-query

I am trying to do the following:

Two queries
1. Get all people that have director 'yes' ticked
2. Get all people that don't have director 'yes' ticked

I have the first query all set up and works well ('people' is a CPT, and director is an ACF of a checkbox 'yes').

```
<?php $directors = get_posts(array(
    'post_type' => 'people',
    'orderby' => 'meta_value',
    'meta_key' => 'last_name',
    'order' => 'ASC',
    'posts_per_page' => -1,
    'meta_query' => array(
        array(
        'key' => 'director',
        'value' => '"yes"',
        'compare' => 'LIKE'
        )
    )
)); ?>
```

What this query does it get all 'people', ordered by their last name, and, using `meta_query` gets all those who have the directors checkbox ticked 'yes'.

So, my issue is that now what I want to do, for the second query, is get all those people where 'director' 'yes' isn't ticked.

[image]

Here is what I have so far:

```
<?php $people = get_posts(array(
    'post_type' => 'people',
    'orderby' => 'meta_value',
    'meta_key' => 'last_name',
    'order' => 'ASC',
    'posts_per_page' => -1,
    'meta_query' => array(
        array(
            'key' => 'company',
        'value' => '"' . get_the_ID() . '"',
        'compare' => 'LIKE'
        ),
        array(
        'key' => 'director',
        'value' => 'yes',
        'compare' => 'NOT LIKE'
        )
    )
)); ?>
```

I have tried a few other compare arguments, but can't seem to get it to work.

Any help or ideas?

Answer (score 1):

If you only have two types (directors and none directors and you allready get all of the directors you can simply use the `post__not_in` parameter, ex:

```
// Get your directors just like you do now
// $directors = get_posts(array( ...
// Then create a simple array with only the post id's of the directors.
$directors_ids = array();
foreach($directors as $d)
    $directors_ids[] = $d->ID;

//then you can get all of the people who are not directors using:
$people = get_posts(array(
    'post_type'      => 'people',
    'orderby'        => 'meta_value',
    'meta_key'       => 'last_name',
    'order'          => 'ASC',
    'posts_per_page' => -1,
    'post__not_in'   => $directors_ids
    )
);
```